# Sharing a variable between multiple custom pages in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am working on an app which consumes web services in json and displays results on a custom page. Currently, I am creating a http client object in the register_page block of the custom page. Since I'll have multiple custom pages, I want to re-use the http client object across them.
I am new to rails and active-admin. Any pointers on the correct way of doing this will be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

```
  session[:variable_to_share] = "Some value"
```

or

```
  @@variable_to_share = "Some value"
```

Using session instead of global variable is actual a better way, as using global variable consumes memory which is expensive.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think that's a clean way. Later may be I would want to share more variables. I am thinking creating a custom class which has all the stuff for consuming web services and creating a model out of it.